# Apply cutouts pattern to multiple objects

Tags: modifiers

I'd like to duplicate a cutout pattern on multiple objects, but with small adjustments on each new object. For example, the rotation and/or origin point may change.

The image below shows the pattern on one object, and the others that I want to copy the cutout on to.
The triangular section will have the pattern rotated so it aligns with the 90deg corner.

Is there a way to copy the cutout to the other objects, or do I need to re-created the pattern (with adjustments) and subtract the pattern from each panel individually?

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Does it a real geometry ... Like cube pattern subtracted by boolean modifier? Does exist a reason not to use texture in this scale?

Comment: I want to be able to see through the panels. I don't know textures well enough to know if that's possible. But if it's possible that would be great!

Comment: How did you created the first one? Seems to me create cube pattern, use boolean modifier for plane should work. Than duplicate cube pattern and use same tech on other planes ... And yes ...could be working probably with texture as well.

Comment: That's correct, I was hoping for something easier. There are many planes to repeat this on.

Answer (score 2):

### Shader – POM (Parallax Occlusion Mapping)

in some cases you can use a single face with *Parallax Occlusion Mapping* shader

[image]

[image]

Inside *POM* node tree is another Nodegroup *POM Iterations* ... each iteration generates a layer with offset specified by Strength value ...

[image]

there you can increase / decrease number of "layers" depend on your needs to result with a smooth depth illusion.

[image]

[image]

---

### Shader – Interior Mapping

There is another similar technique ... again just with a Plane. Each side has unique texture, but you can set as simple color for all as well. Blue front frame is image with transparency so if you need thicker or thinner adjust the image.

*Note: I wanted to use procedural texture for frame, but  get difficulties to translate position of Voronoi texture that can produce nice grid, but since Random was set to zero it didn't move anymore, so probably with Wood texture it could be working.*

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is pretty clever! But it doesn't work as well on a solid object. My object has a thickness, which is important, it's not just for the illusion of depth.

Comment: So...? Just add thickness to your base mesh with classic shader ... More problematic would be probably proper shading or .... for very close look the cut holes far from camera ... I'm not saying it is the best solution, works from case to case ... But if you don't want to use boolean, I don't think there is other than procedural texture ... Sure you can use geometry nodes, but doesn't seems to have bigger advantages than classic boolean.